# Backbone collection not rendered if setModel used when using IE11

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Thoraxjs with backbone. I have a modal window that requires a model and collection to be added. The following code assigns the models and renders a list of items in a child view

```
            // set model
            this.defaultFormView.setModel(model);

            // add filtered collection to view
            this.mediaListView.setCollection(filteredMedia);
```

It works fine in Chrome but IE11 won't render the collection unless I comment out the setModel line. There is no errors, any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else comes across this then update Thorax and Backbone and IE11 will work again.